# What is the meaning of "with the turn of a dial"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of "**with the turn of a dial**"? 
the context is as follow:

> "DC/OS gives you the power to easily scale your services up and down
>   **with the turn of a dial**."

(see [here](https://dcos.io/docs/1.8/overview/features/) for more details)

Comment: In general "with the turn of a dial" can refer to automation or some action made easy.

Comment: Do you know what the noun _dial_ means in English?

Answer (score 1):

Without the context, I can only make an educated guess. There are possibly two meanings: 1) This phrase may mean literally to turn a physical or UI knob. It connotes the easy way of doing something. 2) It can also mean metaphorically to do something without much hassle but there is no real dial in this case.